# Transfer a large folder of photos and videos to iCloud Photos

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, itunes, icloud, photos

I'd like to sync my Google Photos and iCloud photos, mainly because I use iCloud photos a lot more.

I have a large amount of photos on my Google Photos library that I can download as a ZIP folder. I'm just unsure on the way to store these photos in iCloud?

I've tried the iCloud website to upload said photos and videos and it seems very unstable (only allowing uploads of JPEG format, uploading photos and putting them in the wrong chronilogical order etc.).

I can't think of any other better solution than just to sync said photos and videos directly to my iPhone or just use my MacBook to directly upload them.

[image]

It's very annoying. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probably easiest way to get this done is to import the pictures into Photos.app on your Mac and let iCloud do the syncing.

- Open System Preferences -> Apple ID / iCloud (depends on macOS versio)
- Make sure "Photos" has a checkmark

Then start Photos and wait for the photo library you already have to sync to your Mac (may take a while depending on the load on Apples servers, your bandwith etc). Afterwards drag&drop your photos into the Photos window (or right-click on them and add them to Photos via the Sharing entry) and let the sync copy them into iCloud.

As you have already started to upload them directly to iCloud.com you may run into duplicates. Photos won't detect them, so either delete them first (in either iCloud.com or Photos) or don't reimport the photos already available in the library.

Comment: Thanks for that! It's annoying how they won't detect them urgh. I assume thats doing the same as File > Import on the Photos.app ? I'm also assuming this will allow videos to be transferred over?

Comment: @NathanEllis Yes to both. For duplicates https://macpaw.com/gemini usually does a good job

Comment: I guess I'd run that on the photos folder of my mac when everything is synced and downloaded?

Comment: @NathanEllis Yeah, most probably that's the best moment. Depending on the number of potential duplicates you can also just look at all the photos in Photos and pick the duplicates manually.

Comment: You did check that you have enough space in your iCloud account for all the photos I assume?

Comment: Oh yeah, I have 2TB not used so far ahah